# Двоеточие: несоразмерное изобилие

Tags: пунктуация

Один довольно крупный новостной сайт в последнее время стал почти в каждом втором заголовке новости использовать двоеточие. Началось это довольно резко и относительно недавно. Заголовки строятся так:

Завлекательная вульгарная часть: некое разъяснение сути.

Из правил применения этого знака более всего подходит "Двоеточие ставится после одной из частей бессоюзного сложного предложения, за которой последуют одно или несколько других частей". Но мне кажется, что это на самом деле навязываемая например, главным редактором, калька с американского английского.

Каково ваше мнение и есть ли возможность где-то в сети проверить как часто употреблялось двоеточие в заголовках россйский/советских СМИ ранее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Розенталя:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168

**Двоеточие ставится в заголовках,** распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающихся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью и нередко эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части:

Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества; Звёздный рейс: работа на отлично!; Новый герой: поиски и находки; Женщина: семья и работа; Юпитер: планета или звезда?; Перевозка айсбергов: мифы и реальность; Смена правительства: старое наследство, новые возможности; Генетика: стратегия и тактика; Космические лучи: старые или новые?; Энергетика: начало и будущее; Многоэтажные улицы: спасение или бедствие?; Рентгеновский лазер: поиски и надежды.

Завлекательная вульгарная часть: некое разъяснение сути

В принципе такое оформление возможно: в первой части задана тема, а во второй части она конкретизируется.

Comment: Понял. Осталось только удивляться очень резкой смене стиля заголовков. Но по-моему это неприятно читать.

Comment: А как бы Вы исправили форму заголовка, не меняя его содержания?

Comment: я, конечно, специально написал такой заголовок, чтобы убедиться, что это некрасиво. "Правильно" было бы писать так: "Отчего двоеточие так часто применяется в заголовках СМИ?"

Comment: Первый вариант  имеет следующие  положительные стороны: он краток, эмоционален, содержателен (в нем уже высказано ваше отношение к проблеме). Во втором варианте тема только обозначена.  Другой вопрос: надо ли делить заголовок на две части? Здесь однообразие  тоже утомляет. Не помню точно, но, кажется, у Ильфа и Петрова есть такой сатирический персонаж, который любил писать подобные заголовки.

Comment: Мы переходим к живому общению, которое тут не почитается :-). Я согласен с тем, что Вы сказали, но это как раз по-моему и является недостатком: СМИ не должны содержать эмоций и мнений - только перечисление и многосторонний анализ фактов (и однообразие тоже раздражает). Ответ на свой изначальный вопрос я получил вполне - цитатой из Розенталя. Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> Каково ваше мнение и есть ли возможность где-то в сети проверить как часто употреблялось двоеточие в заголовках россйский/советских СМИ ранее?

Да посмотрите подшивки газет, журналов.

Достаточно часто использовалось, другое дело, что глаз не резало. Ваш пример - на грани. Там нет особой насыщенности ни в первой, ни во второй части, так что смотрится действительно неважно. Стилистически. Но с точки зрения пунктуации такой вариант, пожалуй, самый правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Завлекательная вульгарная часть, какой названа часть до двоеточия, является ещё и отсечкой для многих, кто не хочет тратить время на чтение всего новостного анонса (контента). Стало быть эта часть полезна, хотя выглядит выполненной по шаблону и приближается всё больше к табличной форме.

Куда хуже повторы текста шапок внутри сообщений кратких, предполагающих лишь информирование.